# Plotting the solution of a vector stochastic differential equation

Tags: plotting, random, stochastic-calculus

I have a vector stochastic differential equation,

$$\mathrm dq = p\,\mathrm dt\qquad q(0)=0$$
$$\mathrm dp = (-q -p)\mathrm dt+\mathrm dW\qquad p(0)=10$$

This can be entered to give me the process describing **either** p or q, using

```
proc = ItoProcess[
    {{p[t], -p[t]-q[t]}, {{0}, {1}}, XXX[t]},
    {{q, p}, {0, 10}},
    {t,0}
]
```

where `XXX` is either `q` or `p`. The solution can be plotted using the usual method (here for `p`) of

```
ListLinePlot@RandomFunction[proc, {0, 10, .02}, 10]
```

> [image]

However, the situation is more difficult if I want to extract **both** `q` and `p`, as for each simulation it will give me a list of the type (obtained using `Normal`, and by setting `XXX[t]` to `{q[t], p[t]}` in the `ItoProcess`)

```
{{{t0, {q[t0], p[t0]}}, {t1, {q[t1], p[t1]}}, ...}
```

i.e. the times aren't properly distributed over the p/q, and as a consequence I'm having a hard time finding a good way of getting this into a plottable form.

So the questions are:

1. Is there a nice way of getting all components out of a vector stochastic differential equation to plot them alongside each other?
2. If there's none, what's the right hacky approach? Fiddling with `Transpose` and `Flatten`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `"PathComponents"` property of `TemporalData` to split the vector-valued temporal data into the list of `TemporalData` objects and plot those:

```
proc = ItoProcess[{{p[t], -p[t] - q[t]}, {{0}, {1}}}, {{q, p}, {0, 
     10}}, {t, 0}];

td = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 10., 0.02}, 10];

td["PathComponents"]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I forgot looking at `TemporalData`, of which I assumed it was some internal form unsuitable for direct manipulation. Turns out the documentation on it is quite complex.

Answer (score 6):

Please confirm if this is what you were looking for

```
proc = ItoProcess[{{p[t], -p[t] - q[t]}, {{0}, {1}}, {q[t], 
    p[t]}}, {{q, p}, {0, 10}}, {t, 0}];

data = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 10, 0.02}, 10];
```

You could do

```
Plot[Through@data["PathFunction", All][t], {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Another way to visualize this is in the parametric phase space:

```
ListLinePlot[td[[2, 1]], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**---------- Comment reponse ----------**

We can check the structure of underlying expression with **InputForm** and then it is straightforward to use **Part** to extract the sub-expressions:

[image]

Comment: How did you get the `[[2,1]]` part? A little more explanation and this would make a nice remark.

Comment: @David I updated the answer

Comment: Oh, I wasn't expecting you used brute force here.